# Find integral closure of $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(y^3-x^2z)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(y^3-x^2z)$ and let $Q$ be the quotient field of $R$. Find 
>   integral closure of $R$ in $Q$.

I found that
$$R \cong \mathbb{C}[s,st,st^3] \subset \mathbb{C}[s,t],\quad (st^2)^2-(st)(st^3)=0$$
so I expect that the integral closure of $R$ is 
$$\displaystyle \mathbb{C}[s,st,st^3][st^2]=R\left[\frac{\overline{x}\overline{z}}{\overline{y}}\right]$$
How to prove it? Thanks.

Comment: Show that $\mathbb C[s,st,st^2,st^3]$ is integrally closed. This is isomorphic to $\mathbb C[x^3,x^2y,xy^2,y^3]$ which is known as being normal.

Comment: One way is to realize the integral closure you wrote as the toric variety coming from a cone generated by $e_2, 3e_1 -e_2$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2$. Such varieties are normal.